# How to use weather api services in my android app

Tags: android

I am new to the android, I want to develop a sample application to display weather in my android application, for this app how can I use weather API services in my android app to develop my weather application. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JSON,

something like this [http://inchoo.net](http://inchoo.net/mobile-development/android-development/simple-android-json-parsing-example-with-output-into-listactivity/)

However as you see this one is for twitter but you should be able to find a good weather API which support JSON. Have a look at this website : http://www.programmableweb.com/

Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Find a Service that provides weather data. Create an app that will send requests to the Service and get data back. Parse data and show to a user in your app. The rules how to use weather API are different for different services. Find it out on their sites how to use their API.